# How to change wsdl:part name in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is there any way of changing the name of a message part in the WSDL?

I have this in my WSDL:

```
<wsdl:message name="myMethodSoapOut">
     <wsdl:part name="myMethodResult" element="s0:myMethodResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

and I want to change the part name to this:

```
<wsdl:message name="myMethodSoapOut">
     <wsdl:part name="out" element="s0:myMethodResult"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your webmethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public MyReturnInfo MyMethod(MyInputInfo input)
{
//your code
return yourInfo;
}
```

put it like this, the output return as an out parameter:

```
[WebMethod]
public void MyMethod(out MyReturnInfo @out, MyInputInfo input)
{
//your code
@out = yourInfo;
}
```

to use "in" and "out" in the parameters, and keep the element names correct:

```
[WebMethod]
public void MyMethod( [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("myInfoResponse", Namespace = "the_name_space_of_the_response")]out MyReturnInfo @out,
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("myInfoRequest", Namespace = "the_name_space_of_the_request")] MyInputInfo @in)
{
var myVar = DoSomething(@in);
//your code
@out = yourInfo;
}
```

and finally, the wsdl:

```
<wsdl:message name="myInfoSoapIn">
     <wsdl:part name="in" element="s0:myInfoRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
...
<wsdl:message name="myInfoSoapOut">
     <wsdl:part name="out" element="s0:myInfoResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Thanks to PD ;)